# Why is this throwing errors?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I am building a cube from an image in flash. The loader loads a sprite-map of the images:

```
+----++----++----++----++----++----+
|frnt||rght||back||left||top ||bot |
|    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    |
+----++----++----++----++----++----+
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error #2005: Parameter 0 is of the incorrect type. Should be type BitmapData.

On the line `front.draw(src, null, null, null, clip);` (confirmed by commenting out code and *not* receiving an error). But I'm not sure why. I *defined* `src` as `BitmapData`, and a `trace` of `src` produces `[object BitmapData]`.

```
private function loaderCompleteListener(e:Event):void
{
  log('Complete');
  var front:BitmapData,
    right:BitmapData,
    back:BitmapData,
    left:BitmapData,
    top:BitmapData,
    bottom:BitmapData,
    srcData:Bitmap,
    src:BitmapData,
    clip:Rectangle;

  try
  {
    srcData = this._imageLoader.content as Bitmap;
    src = srcData.bitmapData;
    front = new BitmapData(src.height, src.height, false, 0);
    right = new BitmapData(src.height, src.height, false, 0);
    back = new BitmapData(src.height, src.height, false, 0);
    left = new BitmapData(src.height, src.height, false, 0);
    top = new BitmapData(src.height, src.height, false, 0);
    bottom = new BitmapData(src.height, src.height, false, 0);
    clip = new Rectangle(0, 0, src.height, src.height);

    //This is the line that causes the error
    front.draw(src, null, null, null, clip); //<----
    clip.x += src.height;
    right.draw(src, null, null, null, clip);
    clip.x += src.height;
    back.draw(src, null, null, null, clip);
    clip.x += src.height;
    left.draw(src, null, null, null, clip);
    clip.x += src.height;
    top.draw(src, null, null, null, clip);
    clip.x += src.height;
    bottom.draw(src, null, null, null, clip);
  }
  catch ( e:Error )
  {
    log(e.message);
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Edit to add:

One consideration may be the image size. I'm loading an image that's 1866×11196. I will test tomorrow to see if a smaller image works. It may just be that Flash can't handle images beyond a certain size.

Comment: Do you have a decent debugger? If so, can you set a breakpoint on the `srcData = this._imageLoader.content as Bitmap;` line and check if src is actually being assigned the BitmapData object?

Comment: @EyeSeeEm, `log` is a customized JavaScript logger that defaults to `trace` in the flash editor. I can get a correct reading of `src.height` and `src.width`, so I assume that it's being assigned correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum width or length of bitmapdata is 8192, but as stated in the following link, not both. I.e. the total pixel count cannot exceed 16,777,215 pixels.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Answer (score 2):

As Chris pointed out, the built-in maximum for either height or width is 8192 for any BitmapData, so you will not be able to natively use an image that is 11196 in width.

However, there are workarounds, such as the BitmapDataUnlimited class, which you can find [here](http://blog.formatlos.de/2008/05/28/bitmapdataunlimited/).

Answer (score 1):

First I need to thank @Chris, @EyeSeeEm, @Nathan Ostgard for leading me to the reason that I'm receiving an error. My expectation was to receive an `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` if the image wasn't loaded correctly (that seems like an IO error to me at least), but Flash apparently didn't think that one through enough, which is why I'm getting a bogus error.

As everyone pointed out, the AS3 docs specify that the image cannot exceed a specific size.

Flash Player 9:

> The maximum width and maximum height of a BitmapData object is 2880 pixels.

Flash Player 10:

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the maximum size for a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels in width or height, and the total number of pixels cannot exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels high.) In Flash Player 9 and earlier and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the limitation is 2,880 pixels in height and 2,880 in width.

But the important *reason* I'm getting an `ArgumentError` that doesn't seem to make sense is in the next lines in the [CS4 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html):

> Calls to any method or property of a BitmapData object throw an ArgumentError error if the BitmapData object is invalid (for example, if it has `height == 0` and `width == 0`) or it has been disposed of via `dispose()`.

So because my image was wider than `8191px`, it was considered invalid, causing an inscrutable `ArgumentError`.

This makes sense in the context of the `draw` call, but still doesn't explain why I am able to call `src.height` without triggering an error.

Comment: I think these might be two different things. The draw method could very well throw an ArgumentError if images are too big, whereas the .height property only throws the error is the height is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Error is actually 'Parameter 0 is of the incorrect type. Should be type IBitmapDrawable' - not BitmapData. (Well on my machine anyway).

But BitmapData is indeed IBitmapDrawable - the problem lies in the fact an object typed as a certain class that hasn't been constructed, or equals null doesn't actually implement anything.

```
// Example
var src:BitmapData;
trace(src is IBitmapDrawable); // false
```

In your case, if srcData (the Bitmap object) doesn't have bitmapData it will return null and src (the BitmapData) is set to null. So when null is passed into draw() it freaks out because null isn't IBitmapDrawable.

For example if I do the following:

```
var o:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, false, 0);
o.fillRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), 0x334455);

var srcData:Bitmap = new Bitmap(o);
var src:BitmapData;

src = srcData.bitmapData;

trace(src is IBitmapDrawable);

var front:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, false, 0);
front.draw(src as IBitmapDrawable); // works!
```

But if I remove o (the bitmapdata) from srcData, such as:

```
var srcData:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var src:BitmapData;

src = srcData.bitmapData;

trace(src is IBitmapDrawable);

var front:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, false, 0);
front.draw(src as IBitmapDrawable); // Doesn't work!
```

So again, in your case, the Bitmap object isn't receiving any input data.

Comment: if src is null, how can he be calling src.height and .width a couple lines above and not getting null pointer exception?

Comment: One extra consideration that I will append to my answer: the image I was trying to load was very large (1866 x 11196); it may be that flash can't manage an image that large.

Comment: Good pickup EyeSeeEm. @zzzzBov can you place the following before the .draw line. `trace(src is IBitmapDrawable);`

Comment: @zzzzBov I have just ran some tests, it seems anything in the 8500px+ range seems to bug out. If you try to create bitmapdata manually with that size it throws an error.

Comment: @Chris, thanks! I guess my next question will have to be what the maximum supported image size is in flash.

Comment: @zzzzBov To quote the BitmapData constructor docs: "The maximum width and maximum height of a BitmapData object is 2880 pixels. If you specify a width or height value that is greater than 2880, a new instance is not created."